# Can an electromagnetic shield protect spacecraft from incoming radiation?

Tags: radiation

If we used an electromagnetic shield to protect astronauts from radiation, what could we use to power it and could it be possible?

Comment: Probably also worth saying "Hey Billy! Welcome to the site- it seems as if a similar question has previously been asked, does the one link above answer your question :)? If not, could you possibly expand more to make it unique?"